# Executing commands in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm reading the [article](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_01_03) about executing commands by bash shell. On the paragraph regarding shell built-in commands there is an statement:

> When the name of a built-in command is used as the first word of a
>   simple command, the shell executes the command directly, without
>   creating a new process

Can sb. explain me the statement because it's so clear for me. Please give some examples if You can?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between a builtin command and one that is not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11454/108618), [Why is echo a shell built in command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1355/108618).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dir, CD, MD and many other commands are contained in command.com or cmd.exe (for newer Windows operating systems), so they do not have their own files, therefore no new process is created when running them since the command interpreter already runs.

Example:

C:\>CD Windows  - will make C:\Windows your current directory and the command **will not create a new process**.

C:\> Xcopy *.* D: - will make a copy, but **a new process called Xcopy will be created** because Xcopy is an independent file.

It's similar for linux.

Answer (score 2):

Most of GNU/Linux commands are actually executable files (`ls` and `cat` for instance). When you type

```
touch 'Hello World.txt'
```

the `touch` program will be started in a new process, independent from you Bash process.

> When such a program is executed, a new process is created

---

However, built-in commands are executed by the shell itself. For instance,

```
echo 'Hello world!'
```

will be executed by the instance of Bash you are typing in. That makes sense for many other built-in commands, especially `cd` since a process can only change its own working directory.

Comment: ...and that's so although there *is* a `/bin/echo` executable. You can explicitly use the executable by prepending the path. - Sometimes, built-ins create confusion; for example the built-in `echo` might have different options than the binary.

Comment: @Nathan Shiraini: What do You mean by "process can only change its own working directory"? What's process "own" working directory vs "normal" working directory?

Comment: @Mulligan Every Linux process has a "working directory". It's the directory that will be used as a base whenever the process tries to access a file with a relative path (i.e. a path that does not begin with a slash). Since it is Linux that remembers the location of the working directory for each process, they have to ask Linux if they want to change it, but they cannot ask Linux to change another process's working directory (because Linux won't let them).

Comment: For that reason, `cd` would not work if it was started in a new process.